# Java webapp code returning with a path traversal problem when tested in a bot

Tags: java, path-traversal

So I have been given the task of fixing a path traversal problem in a basic Java web app, but I am quite stuck. We are meant to essentially make sure the code is secure, while maintaining functionality (which is the part i am struggling with)

So far I have looked online on how to fix the problems i am receiving, and i managed to fix them, but the bot that tests the code returns with a message saying the application no longer has functionality, but is secure.

The 2 errors I receive are the following:

1) PATH_TRAVERSAL_IN in FileDownload. java
Source File FileDownload. java
Class Name  chatapp. FileDownload
Method Name doGet
Source Line 31

2) PT_RELATIVE_PATH_TRAVERSAL in FileDownload. java
Source File FileDownload. java
Class Name  chatapp. FileDownload
Method Name doGet
Source Line 28

For reference this code is the original where it functions but it is not secure.

```
    private String DOWNLOAD_PATH = new File(".").getCanonicalPath() + 
     "/webapps/webapp/app/download";

    public FileDownload() throws IOException {
    }

    public void init() throws ServletException {
        //To Do
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                       HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {

     !!!String file = request.getParameter("file");
        String downloadPath = DOWNLOAD_PATH + "/" + file;
     !!!File downloadFile = new File(FilenameUtils.getName(downloadPath));

        if (downloadFile.exists()) {
            response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename="+ downloadFile.getName());
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(downloadFile);
            byte[] data = new byte[(int) downloadFile.length()];
            fis.read(data);
            fis.close();

            OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
            out.write(data);
            out.flush();
        }
        else
            response.sendError(404);

    }
```

Does anyone have experience in fixing these sorts of problems? I am sort of confused

Comment: Did you add `!!!` to indicate which lines are 29 and 31, or are those present in the original file? What is the error message you're getting?

Comment: @Haem just to show you guys what lines 29 and 31 are, they are not in the original file

Comment: @Haem do you know how to go about mending it? i've spent all my time since posting this trying to search a fix. I think i am dumb or something lol

Comment: You haven't posted the full error message so it's difficult to tell what's wrong.

Comment: @Haem all edited now

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. I thought you were getting compilation/runtime errors, but those are warnings from some analysis tool.

Comment: Yeah, and I am not sure how to make the code secure, but also function the same. I can make it secure, but then the analysis tool says the code no longer does the same function as it used to when it was not secure

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass sonar's PT\_RELATIVE\_PATH\_TRAVERSAL in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30909672/pass-sonars-pt-relative-path-traversal-in-java) https://find-sec-bugs.github.io/bugs.htm#PATH_TRAVERSAL_IN

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia's article on path traversal [has a proposed method to prevent it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack#Possible_methods_to_prevent_directory_traversal):

> 1. Process URI requests that do not result in a file request, e.g., executing a hook into user code, before continuing below.
> 2. When a URI request for a file/directory is to be made, build a full path to the file/directory if it exists, and normalize all characters (e.g., `%20` converted to spaces).
> 3. It is assumed that a 'Document Root' fully qualified, normalized, path is known, and this string has a length ''N''. Assume that no files outside this directory can be served.
> 4. Ensure that the first ''N'' characters of the fully qualified path to the requested file is exactly the same as the 'Document Root'.
> 5. If so, allow the file to be returned.
> 6. If not, return an error, since the request is clearly out of bounds from what the web-server should be allowed to serve.

So, you'd create a second file object from `DOWNLOAD_PATH`, then use `getCanonicalPath`  to see that the path of the file to be downloaded starts with the path of the download directory.

With this done, you'd add a `@SuppressWarnings` annotation to the method to hide the warnings that are now properly handled.